# Image Box is getting the deleted image in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have an image box which is given the URL if it is not a post back. While in a  page  I want to change this picture. I delete the picture from the folder where it exist and uploaded using a file upload a picture with the same name. question is that the the new picture is uploaded to the folder. But the image is still the previous and on refreshing the page still it is there I'm using visual studio 2012 and even I shutdown the machine and restart it the image which I deleted is not in the folder but the image box is still showing the deleted picture.

```
public void savepicture(string tablename)
{
    Int32 newid = (objclsfn.newidgeneratore(tablename) + 1);
    File.Delete(Server.MapPath(objnames.StudentsPictures + newid + objnames.imageformate));
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(objnames.StudentsPictures + newid + objnames.imageformate));

    if (Image1.ImageUrl == "") 
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl=(objnames.StudentsPictures + newid + objnames.imageformate); 
    }
    else
    {
       Image1.ImageUrl = "";
       Image1.ImageUrl=(objnames.StudentsPictures + newid + objnames.imageformate); 
    }


}
```

The button event is :

```
protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    savepicture("Students");
}
```

Comment: Maybe its from temp memory or browser cache. Did you try clear cache?

Comment: hit ctrl+f5 in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your PC Cookies and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Can you please check, what is the path of the image in the browser developer tools, make sure the path is same as you expect it to be from where you have deleted the image.

Else as my friend above suggested, clear the browser cookies and cache.